# Typescript compiler error. The name 'boolean' does not exist in the current scope

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm trying to put together an environment that uses Typescript.

I've used npm to get typescript on my OS X, downloaded the latest jquery/jquery.d.ts from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Running tsc in the command line (using the integrated provided the same outcome) ended with the following error:

```
The name 'boolean' does not exist in the current scope
```

Problems arose too (similar, but the unfound type was "_element") with the lib.d.ts type annotation file.

I'm using typescript compiler version 0.9.0.0.

**Later edit:**

I'm definitely lost, tried getting the jquery.d.ts from

http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe3bc0bfce1f#bin/jquery.d.ts

and now I've come up with a diferent problem while compiling it:

```
jquery.d.ts(37,18): error TS1023: Index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'
```

Is there a version mismatch between the ts files and the compiler I'm using and if so, how can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this version : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts

Also try doing an uninstall / install of typescript.

```
npm uninstall typescript 
npm uninstall -g typescript 
npm install typescript
```

Also before doing that I am curious what `tsc -version` shows you. Did it change after the above steps?

Comment: It's 0.9.0.0 right now and it works just fine with that jquery.d.ts definition. Somewhere along the way I probably messed up something. Thank you.

Comment: I still have this problem. I use `jquery.d.ts` you provided and I've tried tsc v. 0.9.0 and 0.9.1

Comment: Thanks. Updated answer : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts